# How to properly use logger and how to use the same logger in both Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Sorry if this a very basic question, but after I checked a lot entries here (and tried to implement solutions) I still do not have an answer...

The goal is to have a ruby class which could be used withot editions (or with as little editions as possible) in both ruby scripts and as ruby on rails model. I want to have the following

```
logger.info 'some tracing'
```

However when I put such statement in ruby class I'm getting error messages - unknow method logger in both ruby and ruby on rails. Well. when I modify it such way

```
Rails.logger.info 'some tracing'
```

It starts to work in rils, but of course does not work in ruby without rails. What I'm doing wrong?
I read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger but I still confused, since examples from the section 'send messages' do not work. 
So_ sorry again, but I see no other possibility as to connect to "the hive mind" ans ask for help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses the ruby logger by default.

Take a look at the API doc here : [Logger (Ruby 2.0)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)

Here is an example:

```
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.level = Logger::WARN

logger.debug("Created logger")
logger.info("Program started")
logger.warn("Nothing to do!")
```

**EDIT**

Usage:

```
require 'logger' 

class MyClass 

  def initialize
    @logger = logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    @logger.level = Logger::WARN
  end

  def say_something
    @logger.info("You can't see me I'm not important enough")
    @logger.warn("I'm visible")
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi, @basgys, since this is a ruby class, I have to do something like that  

     require 'logger'  

    class myClass

       def initialize 
            \@logger = Logger.new
            ….
      end

     def someMethod
           \@logger.info 'some trace'
     end
    end

is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, @basgys I needed some structured text in my answer and entered <return>

Comment: thatnks a lot. I think_ tht some examples I saw were misleading, just because they used 'logger' not as method, but as variable, and both require and =Logger.new statements were ommited there